# python string split mystery IndexError

Tags: python, list, indexing, range

Okay ... this is a mystery to me 
the below code prints:

```
['03:20:01', 'PM', '262144', '16176136', '98.41', '547744', '11459404', '2096128',   '312', '0.01', '0']
['12:30:01', 'PM', '261748', '16176532', '98.41', '547600', '11459084', '2096128', '312', '0.01', '0']
['10:50:11', 'PM', '257516', '16180764', '98.43', '548064', '11460312', '2096128', '312', '0.01', '0']
```

but when I try to print c[2] it gives me:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What am I missing ?

The code seems straightforward

```
cmd = 'sar -r -f /xactly/apps/sar/sjcxtlycomp22s/sa05 |sort -g -k4' 
high = subprocess.Popen([cmd],
      stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
      stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
      stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        shell=True)

memuse = False
count = 0 

sep = re.compile('[\s]+')
for line in high.stdout:
    if line:
        line = line.strip()
        count += 1
        c = sep.split(line)
        print c
```

Comment: can you please add `len(c)` in in addition to `print c` and let us know what you see ?

Comment: Where are you putting the `print c[2]` statement? (also, and this isn't your problem, are you aware that `re` is overkill here since strings have a `.split()` method that splits on whitespace by default?)

Comment: @ Wooble, it is very much obvious of the code and the error that the `c[2]` is printed after `c = sep.split(line)`. Otherwise, Index error would not know that `c` is a list.
Also, if he prints it after the loop, the last value of c (which would be a list) would be retained.

Comment: fixed ... with the addition of "if count > 3:" ... I needed to skip the first three lines.

Comment: @GodMan: well it was also pretty obvious that OP was lying about the output, so why not being lying about the error message and code, too? (voting to close as too localized)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to skip the first three lines of data so I modified it with:

```
sep = re.compile('[\s]+')
   for line in high.stdout:
       if line:
           line = line.strip()
           count += 1
           if count > 3:
               c = sep.split(line)
               print c[4]
```

Comment: if that solves your problem, accept your own answer please so we can move on.

Comment: unfortunately I have to wait two days :(